# Оптимальный и быстрый путь создание нового проекта на Laravel?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel

Здравствуйте. Работаю в маленькой фирме, где фактически я один работаю с фреймворком Laravel, остальные на друпал и верстальщики.

Интересуют следующие, общие, связанные между собой, вопросы по правильному подходу к разработке проекта, например на фрейморку Laravel:

**1)** используете ли вы для создании нового проекта на фрейворке какой то CRUD-генератор, boilerplate, готовую админку (с фронтедом и бекендом), цмс (например octoberCMS)? Или же на каждом проекте создаете функционал с нуля, используя сам фрейворк и php-пакеты?

**2)** Делаете ли вы для каждой подобной сущности, (например Новости, Статьи, Продукты) отдельные таблицы и модели, или это все хранится в одной (например Ноды как в Drupal), с указание типа, и каждый тип имеет свои заданные, например в конфигах поля (катинки, текст,…)?

**3)** Стоит ли самому делать и использовать под себя, на основе Laravel, какое то универсальное решение, типа админки? Или функциональное и одновременно универсальное создать не возможно, и лучше писать на фрейворку с нуля? … и не тратить время на создание своих велосипедов

**4)** Например, на большинстве сайтов, нужен функционал для управления пользователями, их правами, загрузка файлов, картинок, катетеризация (таксономия как например друпале), мета теги, переменные. И это все писать, та даже ставить и настраивать готовые пакеты выходит не очень быстро. Как вы это делаете?

*ps.* Хотелось бы увидеть ответы людей, которые прошли уже это.

Comment: Всегда делаю все с нуля. Решать как использовать БД, безусловно исключительно вам. Не забывайте, что друпал это cms, а Laravel - фрейморк. Что касается админки, если подразумевается повторное её использование, я бы на вашем месте написал свою, чтобы хорошо в ней разбираться и добавлять разделы по мере необходимости. Пользователей тоже делаю руками, по мере необходимости.

Comment: Делаю все с нуля, но есть компоненты на vuejs datagrid, datacreate, data-view-edit, под них делаю rest API через маршруты api, там соответственно fractal + entrust для отдачи моделей по правам и ролям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем каждый рас изобретать велосипед с квадратными колесами...??? Для этого придумали концепцию повторного использования кода композеры и т.д чтоб не нужно было разработчику тратить время на тривиальные вещи а сосредоточится на конкретной задаче. Вскоре у вас будет список пакетов которые вы будете подключать за 10 мин. Если вас в них что то не устраивает вы их можете форкнуть и переделать как вам захочется. Итог этого всего это экономия огромного количества времени вашей жизни которое вам никто не вернет.